# Error messages refusing to display [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay so I will try to explain this the best I can.

I have a TopicsController that has a Show method inside of it that loops through the topics model and displays all the needed information and below it I have a form for my posts model. Problem is.. The error messages refuse to display if its fails validation. I've tried EVERYTHING and I don't know what else to do. I have a custom error partial that should work.

Controller:

```
  def create
    @community_post.user_id = current_user.id
    @community_post.community_topic_id = params[:community_topic_id]

    if @community_post.save
      redirect_to "/community_topics/#{@community_post.community_topic_id}", notice: 'Community post was successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to "/community_topics/#{@community_post.community_topic_id}", notice: 'Community post was NOT successfully created.'
      @community_post.community_topic_id = nil
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<h1> Submit reply </h1>

<% @community_post  = CommunityPost.new %>

<%= form_for(@community_post) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'error_messages_posts' %>

    <%= f.label :text %>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :community_topic_id, @community_topic.id %>

    <br>

    <%= f.submit "Submit reply" %>
<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
    <% if @community_post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@community_post.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @community_post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are redirecting the flow to `/community_topics/#{@community_post.community_topic_id}`, error values in variable `@community_post` are lost.

You can either render the same form again or pass the error message in the notice (Some thing like `redirect_to "/community_topics/#{@community_post.community_topic_id}", notice: "Community post was NOT successfully created. Errors : #{@community_post.errors.full_messages.join(', ')}")`

Thanks.

Comment: Okay but the problem is the show I have to render is in a different controller and I haven't been able to make it work. What exactly do I need?

Comment: The notice message works but I'd like it to format properly under the form like it does for all my other forms in my application for consistency.

Comment: I tried 'render :controller => 'community_topics', :action => 'show', :id => @community_post.community_topic_id' but its just trying to render a show for the controller i'm in (community_posts)

Comment: Create a action `new` where you will set `@community_post  = CommunityPost.new` and use that variable to create initial form. Now in the create action, when _@community_post.save_ fails, render the new form `render :new` (remember to remove `<% @community_post  = CommunityPost.new %>` from the view)

Comment: The reason I'm doing it in the view is because community post does not have its own view for creating it. It is createable from another controllers view. Their basically supposed to be posts like in Stack Overflow you have the main question and you have the replies well the view I posted is the snippet off code at the bottom of the page where the question is listed that allows you to reply onto it. I'm used to doing things in a purly MVC everything has page and its all ordered RESTFuly and all that but obviously trying to do things slightly different has confused everything a tad.

Comment: Then ideally your community_post_form view should be a partial where you will pass the object of `@community_post` in locals, Something like `render partial: 'community_post_form', locals: {community_post: @community_post}`.
Anyways when you will redirect back to the community_topics show page, value in @community_post will not sustain. You will have to write your own algorithm for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance with in the form with

```
<% @community_post  = CommunityPost.new %>
```

now this object does not have any error message with it thats why you are unable to see any error message. also you are redirecting it to other action that action is unaware of your object .message so you are doing every thing wrong

Comment: I'm aware of exactly what you are saying because, I saw the exact same thing however, It was not working with this remedied in the first place. It is probably this PLUS the use of the redirect_to which both are causing my problem. I'm having difficulty getting render to actually render a method from another controller however making this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line `@comminity_post = CommunityPost.new()`, as it creates a new post without any errors.

Additionally render the form from your **create** action.

```
render :new
```

Rendering views from another controller

```
render :template => "controller/action"
```